# Dynamically Calling ASP.NET MVC Global Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to dynamically execute am ASP.NET MVC global helper function (not HtmlHelper extension method), similar to using a reflection approach to calling a method on a class?  I need to be able to invoke a method dynamically, and inject the response into a view.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just use partial views?

Comment: Does it have to be a dynamic method? How are you deciding which method to store? And couldn't you use that information in a switch statement?

Comment: You can only use a switch if you use a finite list of entries; if I'm trying to build a reusable component that can be fed the helper name, then reflect on the methods of that helper, that's a step above a switch...

Comment: that doesn't sound like a job for helpers.  It sounds like a job partials do already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're basing the decision of which helper to execute on values the view has access to, you can encapsulate each helper function in a partial view (or just refactor the helpers as partials) and render them either directly with `@Html.RenderPartial`. If you want more isolation between the two views, and more flexibility, go with `@Html.RenderAction` instead  (but note that you're reinvoking a medium-large part of the MVC pipeline when you invoke a child action from a view).